# Wordpress unescape text on mysql?

Tags: mysql, text

on database i have field `desc` with value `\'test\'` actually the input is `'test'`

when i gather the field for display it on table, it show `\'test'\` not `'test'`

anyone can know how to change the value become `'test'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to remove the slashes. For example:

```
echo stripslashes( $field );
```